# Is it ethical to downvote competing answer?

Tags: discussion

Here is example:

[How do I format the Custom Field DateTime?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/how-do-i-format-the-custom-field-datetime)

Right now there are two answers. Mine is ... well I hope it is decent. Answer provided by @TeckniX is ... strange (and link is at least puzzling). If I came across this situation I would most likely upvote my question and maybe even downvoted other one.

Now, I am not easy on downvotes and I would never downvoted without comment. So in this case 'my opponent' (and everyone else) would know who downvoted him/her and it would most likely look that I am doing this to promote my answer.

So I have dilemma: To downvote or not to downwote? ... or just sit and wait.

Disclaimer and request: Please don't upvote my question or downvote other one. I am just interested in opinions on this issue since this is not the first time I am facing this dilemma.

Comment: TeckniX answer is regarding date formats in DVWP or CQWP using extension methods. The question isnt entirely clear where the date format should be used.

Comment: I didn't want to discuss about original question here. Maybe my dilemma isn't valid in this case (maybe my answer deserves to be downvoted) but it is still dilemma: What to do? Not on this particular question but in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should vote down an answer if it is incorrect.. not because it is someone elses.

Further reading:

- [The answer to tactical downvoting problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem)
- [Is the “down-voting (most) all answers that aren’t yours” pattern considered harmful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/is-the-down-voting-most-all-answers-that-arent-yours-pattern-considered-harm)
- [What should be done to people who downvote strategically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17538/what-should-be-done-to-people-who-downvote-strategically)

Comment: Some interesting reading here. Problem in my case is that answer is not incorrect - it is... I am not sure what is it. If there was some obvious technical error in it it would receive -1 instantly.

Comment: @VedranRasol If you are not sure whether it's a helpful answer then don't downvote it. Other people will if necessary.

Comment: They will probably upvote the more complete / helpful answer. IMO, I reserve the downvote for very obvious occasions.

Comment: Same opinion as Kit and @alexangas, but kind of stumped at the question: is this really a problem? I havent noticed this kind of behaviour, but maybe I just havent been paying attention? Anyways its quite clear: downvoting should **never** have anything to do with you posting another Q.